# TypeScript: Не обнаруживаются библиотека при импорте, хотя она имеет определения типов (.d.ts)

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

При подключении библиотеки [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk), новейшие версии которой имеют определения типов, компилятор вывел ошибку `TS2307: Cannot find module 'chalk'`:

[image]

Структура библиотеки `chalk` имеет такой вид:

[image]

Я попробовал подключить библиотеку [colors.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) взамен, которая тоже имеет определения типов "из коробки" - та же ошибка.

Думаю, я что-то делаю не так. Все библиотеки, которые я использовал ранее, не включали в себя определения типов, потому я устанавливал типы из [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). Здесь же библиотека имеет определения типов "из коробки". Я думал, что будет достаточно её просто импортировать, но оказалось, что нет.

На англоязычном StackOverflow мне предложили [такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55373047/4818123):

> Эту ошибку можно устранить следующей последовательностью команд:
>
> ```
> npm install chalk 
> npm install each-async 
> npm install indent-string
> ```

Я пока ещё не пустил в ход это решение, потому что мне непонятна логическая связь между тем, что TypeScript не видит нужные определения типов, и тем, что нужно устанавливать на первый взгляд совершенно не имеющие отношения к делу библиотеки `each-async` и `indent-string`. Засорять свой проект зависимостями, не понимая, зачем они нужны, я не собираюсь.

### Сведения о моём проекте

Мой проект собирается Webpack-ом для `Node.js`. Разумеется, webpack сконфигурирован соответствующим образом (в том числе, настроена опция `target: 'node'` и используется плагин `nodeExternals`).

---

Ссылка на проект с воспроизведением проблемы: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aro46dXM9rTw6IsaTv5TEzzXEp_sCJTQ/view?usp=sharing

Потребуется установленный Node.js, а также установка зависимостей в проект (`npm i`).

Comment: вам же ошибку выдает не компилятор, а IDE, вы пробовали компилировать? у `chalk` дефолтный экспорт, замените также на `import Chalk from 'chalk'`

Comment: @overthesanity, Благодарю Вас за комментарий. К сожалению, эту ошибку выдаёт и компилятор тоже, причём эта ошибка -` TS2307:` : Cannot find module 'chalk'.` Попробовал, как Вы сказали, но ничего не изменилось (что логично - если модуль не найден, тот не имеет значения, дефолтный импорт/экспорт или нет).

Comment: тут вряд ли кто-то сможет разобраться в вашей проблеме, пока вы не сделаете minimal reproduction

Comment: @overthesanity, да не воспрос. Вот [ссылка на исходники](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aro46dXM9rTw6IsaTv5TEzzXEp_sCJTQ/view?usp=sharing) с минимальным воспроизведением (потребуется nodejs, а так же выполнение команды `npm i`).

Comment: `"moduleResolution": "node"` добавьте и все заработает

Comment: @overthesanity, Сработало! Оформите, пожалуйста, это в виде ответа, чтобы я мог сделать Вас победителем конкурса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор не знает где искать модули, он видит что этот импорт неотносительный, но проблема в том, что у вас не указана ни модульная система, ни стратегия разрешения модулей. Вы можете установить флаг компилятора:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

И это также автоматически за вас установит статегию `node` по умолчанию, либо установить флаг компилятора:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```